# How to check version of Unity package in project through script

Tags: unity, asset-management, asset-workflow

I'm writing an asset that will be used by many people, but it depends on TextMeshPro (TMP). I ran into a bug in TMP that can only be fixed by upgrading to a preview version. I want to warn users that install my asset that they need to upgrade their TMP version if they are using a prior version. Surprisingly, I can't find this anywhere online or in the docs.

just something like

```
if (TextMeshPro.version < MyAsset.RequiredTMPVersion) {
    Debug.LogError("Need to upgrade TMP");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Unity's **[PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-api.html)**.

First you search for the package you need info of (TMP) with [PackageManager.Client](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PackageManager.Client.html?_ga=2.117411713.620614235.1585159338-1877928021.1585159338) (I think it will look something like this: `var tmp = Client.Search("com.unity.textmeshpro").Result;`, be aware that `.Result` is synchronous, maybe there's a better way to implement this using Tasks).

Then you get the package's info (version) with [PackageManager.PackageInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PackageManager.PackageInfo.html) (something like `tmp.version`). Done.

Comment: The second line needed to be `tmp[0].version` since the Result is an array. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I jumped the gun. The result is null. `PackageInfo[] textmeshpro = Client.Search("com.unity.textmeshpro").Result;`

Comment: The result is coming as null? Maybe it's due to the `.Result`, I didn't see it being used that way in [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-api.html), try an _async_ approach, it might work.